# /users/{id}/answers - broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, answers

Have not checked other routes, as I am busy with other things, but a failing test pointed this out...

**GOOD:** http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/users/242897/answers?min=4&sort=votes

```
{
  "total": 37,
  "page": 1,
  "pagesize": 30,
  "answers": [
    {
      "answer_id": 2846656,
      "accepted": false,
      "answer_comments_url": "/answers/2846656/comments",
      "question_id": 2349378,
      "owner": {
        "user_id": 242897,
        "user_type": "registered",
        "display_name": "code poet",
        "reputation": 10692,
```

**BAD:??** http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/users/242897/answers?min=5&sort=votes

```
{
  "total": 25,
  "page": 1,
  "pagesize": 30,
  "answers": []
}
```

**BAD:??** http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/users/242897/answers?min=6&sort=votes

```
{
  "total": 17,
  "page": 1,
  "pagesize": 30,
  "answers": []
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/users/242897

Comment: confirmed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed.

Comment: I wish you could provide us with some info about what was wrong.  We aren't the casual facebook users who have no clue why their friends list could be broken for a while.  We are genuinely interested in this API.

Comment: @jjnguy - Even though the API has been frozen, we're continuing to  improve performance.  One of the recent changes had an off by one error that, ironically, didn't affect the lots-o-date users common in our test cases.

Answer (score 2):

Confirming weirdness with the `/users/{id}/answers` route. For example, these two queries yield completely different results, although the second one only has a `pagesize` and `page` parameters:

- http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/users/180784/answers
- http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/users/180784/answers?pagesize=10&page=1

I would have expected the first 10 results of the first query to be identical to the second query.

It seems the sorting is messed up in some way?